# Extracting selected value from a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

how do i extract out the selected text and values from a list box.
Here's how I populate the list box

```
           // Populate ListBox

            ListItem lstListItem = new ListItem();

            int intRecordCount = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i <= intRecordCount - 1; i++)
            {
                lstListItem.Text = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SN_Notes"];
                lstListItem.Value = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"];
                this.lstNote.Items.Add(lstListItem);
            }
```

then when i try to fetch the selected values, It return null value. I'm using Winform / VS2010

```
           intRecordCount = lstNote.Items.Count;

           for (int i = 0; i <= intRecordCount - 1; i++)
           {
                  lstNote.SelectedIndex = i;
                  strID = lstNote.SelectedValue.ToString(); // Always return Null Value
           }
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: have you selected any value in first hand also you can bound your control to Listbox rather than iterating datatable.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Populate ListBox
int intRecordCount = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i <= intRecordCount - 1; i++)
{
    ListItem lstListItem = new ListItem();
    lstListItem.Text = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SN_Notes"];
    lstListItem.Value = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"];
    this.lstNote.Items.Add(lstListItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is baaad :|

```
    // Populate ListBox
    int intRecordCount = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i <= intRecordCount - 1; i++)
    {
        ListItem lstListItem = new ListItem();
        lstListItem.Text = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SN_Notes"];
        lstListItem.Value = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"];
        this.lstNote.Items.Add(lstListItem);
    }
```

You need to create a new instance of `ListItem` on each iteration - otherwise, your `ListBox` will contain multiple copies of a single `ListItem`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't bind correctly the `ListBox`. You should try using this code:

```
lstListItem.DataSource = objDataSet.Tables[0];
lstListItem.DisplayMember = "SN_Notes";
lstListItem.ValueMember = "ID";
```